# Python: loop in elif condition

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

I'm running Python 3.

Is it possible to put a loop in the condition for `elif`? Here's the basic idea I'm trying to achieve. The number of items in the list is not constant.

```
if some_condition:
    do this
elif [ x.method() for x in list ]:
    do this to x
else:
    do something else
```

Now, this comes to my mind:

```
if some_condition:
    do this
for x in list:
    if x.method():
        do this to x
        break
```

But I'm trying to avoid running all the if statements, there's a lot of stuff going on in them. And I would like to get it in the `elif` part specifically and not in `else`.

### Edit / more clarification:

It seems what I would need is `any( x.method() for x in list )` but also with a reference to `x` so that I can then use `x` if the condition was true.

Here's the whole concept I'm trying to get again:

```
if condition:
    do this
elif list[0].method():
    do this to list[0]
elif list[1].method():
    do this to list[1]
...
elif list[n].method():
    do this to list[n]
else:
    do this
```

where `method()` is some method that returns `True` or `False`, and `n` is the size of the list and not a constant.

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of what you're trying to do? What are the contents of `list`? What is `some_condition`? What is `do this`? What is `x.method()`? What is `do this to x`? What is `do something else`? Exactly what output do you expect to see?

Comment: @Kevin I added another clarification of the concept, maybe the clearest so far, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what you want -- to have it entirely in the `elif` -- is possible. You'd have to evaluate whether there is `any` such value in the list, and then bind it to `x` *in the condition*. As far as I know, this is not possible in Python's syntax. [You can not do an assignment in the condition](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement), and while the loop variable in a list comprehension *can* "leak" to the outside scope, the same is *not* true for a generator.

```
>>> if any(x for x in range(10) if x >= 5):
...     print x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> if any([x for x in range(10) if x >= 5]):
...     print x
9
```

In the second case (list), we have a reference to `x`, but it is the last value from the entire list, and in the first case (generator), `x` can not be resolved at all.

---

Instead, here's another variant, using a generator expression to combine the `for` with the `if`, and adding an `else` to the `for` to enumate your final `else` clause.

```
if some_condition:
    print "do this"
else:
    for x in (x for x in lst if foo(x)):
        print "do this to", x
        break
    else:
        print "do something else"
```

Comment: If you take a look at the last clarification I added to the question (which I think is the clearest so far), would you say it's not possible? But thanks for the `for ... else`, I totally forgot about that one (naturally). It's close enough to what I need.

Comment: @tobias_k  Just an update, I have tried second case in python 3.6, it is not working

Comment: @BhargavKatkam Right, that "leaking out of a list comprehension" thing was fixed in Python 3. Note, however, that it did not "work" in Python 2, either, as `x` will have the last value from the list, which is evaluated entirely before the `any` is applied.

Answer (score 3):

I see now. The Pythonic way of doing what your updated edit says is to make a for loop and break out after you find your first item and act on it, and use the almost unknown and unused "else" of a loop.

Since the "for / else" idiom is so rarely used, you will need to add a comment about it, for future readers.

```
if some_test:
    first_action()
else:
    for item in list:
        if item.method():
            do_this(item)
            break   # process no more of list
    else:   # for-else only entered if no break from the list!
        final_action()
```

Read up on [loop elses in the Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops%20loop%20elses).

Comment: Very true, and that's what was already suggested. I did totally forget about that one.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ x.method() for x in list ]:
```

You ask, is it possible? Yes. What does it do, though? Probably not what you intend.

For the number of items in *list*, it will fabricate one value in the resulting list. For list values, only a list of zero length will be False. [False, False, False] is True, so the body of the condition will be executed.

You may be looking for **all()** or **any()** if *x.method()* is supposed to influence the following condition decision.

```
if all(x.method() for x in list):   # will require that every *x.method* call return truth.
```

Likewise, you may want

```
if any(x.method() for x in list):   # only one required. May not do every .method if it can stop early. Beware side-effects.
```

Comment: This does not give you a reference to `x`, so you basically would have to do it all again to find the right `x`

Comment: Yes, what I would like to have is `any()` but with a reference to x.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly possible to do what you want, but you can do something similar with list comprehensions:

```
if some_condition:
    do this
else:
    res = [x for x in list if x.method()]
    if res:
        do something to res[0]
    else:
        do something else
```

To avoid do `x.method()` for every value, you could also use `itertools.dropwhile`.  The following approach will keep checking `x.method()` until it finds one that is true, then stop and return just that value of `x`.  If it doesn't find any that are true, it will do something else.

```
from itertools import dropwhile
if some_condition:
    do this
else:
    try:
        res = next(dropwhile(lambda x: not x.method(), x))
        do something to res
    except StopIteration:
        do something else
```

Comment: This will execute `x.method` for all `x`

Comment: So would the syntax that the question proposed, if it worked.

Comment: But if you read the question and examine the examples, you see that OP does not want to execute it for each `x` and that he `break`s after the first match.

Comment: It is not clear to me, but anyway I have added a variant that does not have this issue.

Comment: This is still in `else`, not in `elif`.

Comment: Yes, doing it in elif would be far more complicated.

Comment: I thought of that `try/except` hack, too, but you do not need `dropwhile`. Just do `next(x for x in list if x.method())`

Answer (score 0):

This could work as long as you don't need a reference to x outside of the elif block. This feels closest to the syntax you are asking for, but I would still probably go with either Kevin or Tobias's answers as they are more explicit and readable.

```
 def check_and_do(x):
    b = x.method()
    if b:
        do this to x
    return b

if condition:
    do this
elif any(check_and_do(x) for x in list):
    pass  # Already did this to x in check_and_do
else:
    do something else
```